# How to call one of multiple returns?

Tags: python

```
def sudoku_solver(sudoku):
    l = [0, 0]
    if not find_empty_location(sudoku, l):
        return True
    row = l[0]
    col = l[1]
    for num in range(1, 10):
        if check_location_is_safe(sudoku, row, col, num):
            sudoku[row][col] = num
            if sudoku_solver(sudoku):
                return  True,sudoku            
            sudoku[row][col] = 0
    return False

def P():
    a = np.zeros((9,9))
    if sudoku_solver(sudoku):
        a = sudoku_solver(sudoku)[1]
    else:
        a = 1
    return a
```

There are two returns, `True` and `sudoku`. How can I call `sudoku` only in function P? When I run the function `P()`, it will show
`'bool' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: `sudoku_solver` doesn't appear to return a tuple, only the code fragment above `P` that *calls* `sudoku_solver`.

Comment: There's 2 functions missing in this code. `check_location_is_safe` and `sudoku_solver` and `P` is never called.

Comment: if `sudoku_solver` returns 2 elements, you can retrieve them like this: `first, second = sudoku_solver(argument)`

Answer (score 0):

When you see

```
return  True,sudoku
```

you can catch the returned values like so

```
result, sudoku = my_function()
```

or if you've no interest in result

```
_, sudoku = my_function()
```

---Edit---

It seems your question centers around the two returns. Namely

```
return True,sudoku
```

versus

```
return False
```

That's adds unnecessary complexity. Can I suggest you simplify by instead using

```
return sudoku
```

and then later

```
return None
```

That means you can check the returned value like so

```
sudoku = my_function()
if (sudoku):
    // Do something here
else:
    // Do something else
```

Comment: Yes, and more Pythonic than my approach.

Comment: thanks for reply. The problem is that i want to return Sudoku only. But I don't know  how...if i delete the return True,the function will be wrong

Comment: @HAOZHANG if you only want to return sudoku at the one place and a bool at the other, you can check the return type with `isinstance(result, bool)` in your P() function

Comment: @Uli Sotschok in fact i just want to return Sudoku or just call Sudoku in P function, but it shows 'bool' object is not subscriptable however Sudoku is not a bool type...

Comment: In this line you try to get the second element of a tuple: sudoku_solver(sudoku)[1]. This is possible when the function returned a tuple with two values. But the sudoku_solver function has two parts, where it only returns a bool. This is where the error occurs. I don&#39;t exactly know what your function does, but you need either first check if the sudoku_solver function returned a tuple or a bool. You can add try except. You can change sudoku_solver to always return a tuple

Comment: Expanded answer based on comments

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function return a single value that would be either None or the sudoku data.

Python treats None as false so your condition could then be:

```
...
if sudoku_solver(sudoku):
   a = sudoku_solver(sudoku)
   ...
```

Note that if sudoku_solver() is a complex and time consuming function, you will want to place its result in a variable BEFORE testing the condition so that it is not executed twice (as would be the case in the above condition)

```
...
a = sudoku_solver(sudoku)
if a:
   ...
```

Another option would be to systematically return a tuple with the boolean and the sudoku data (or None).

Your return statements would have to be changed to `return True,sudoku` and `return False,None`

Then your condition could use indexing directly:

```
...
if sudoku_solver(sudoku)[0]:
   a = sudoku_solver(sudoku)[1]
   ...
```

but again, you probably don't want to execute the function twice so :

```
...
ok,a = sudoku_solver(sudoku)
if ok :
   ...
```

Another thing is that, if you're passing sudoku as a parameter, you have to realize that your function will modify the content of the calling variable even when it returns False.  That may not be what you want but if it is, then there is no point in returning a second value because the caller's instance of the sudoku variable will already be modified and available.

Answer (score -1):

You can't return multiple objects from a function, but you can return a container object, such as a list or tuple, that contains multiple member objects. Try using

```
return [ True, sudoku ]
```

Comment: `return  True, sudoku` is the same as `return  (True, sudoku)`. So this answer is misleading.

Comment: I agree with the above comment - you can return True, sudoku